# Dart board probability using line method with Poisson application

Tags: probability, self-learning, poisson-distribution

You randomly throw darts at a dartboard, **one dart every second**. Suppose that every dart independently hits the dartboard at distance X from the center, where **X is a Unif[0,30] random variable**. Your target, **the bullseye, is located around the center and has radius 2.**

**Suppose you throw darts for 1 minute. Approximate the probability that you score more than 5 bullseye.**

the solutions given are, once using Bin and then  using poisson in this manner:

[image]

Poisson(4) - RV Y 
P(Y>5) = 1- $\frac{643}{15} e^{-4}$

The Poisson  :  Poiss($\lambda$) = $\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$

so in their solution they are stating $\lambda = 4$ and K is supposed to be k=60 , no?

because $\frac{4^{60}}{60!}$  doesn't equal to $\frac{643}{15}$

Is it a typo or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

For the Poisson one, we are finding the probability of $Y>5$. We take away the probability of $Y\leq 4$. Overall this is $1-\sum_{k=0}^4 \frac{e^{-4}4^k}{k!}$